# CSS display divs in timed intervals as tool tips

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to get about 8 or 9 divs to fade in and fade out in timed intervals.  One after another in 5 second intervals overlapping each other by 1 second.  I am not really sure where to start.  I am thinking the CSS and then create a js for an onclick array...

Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: Try adapting this to your needs http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/9Zxew/

Comment: Here is a screenshot link to what I am trying to accomplish.  All the tool tips are positioned absolute and in there own div.  http://74.39.250.15/tool_tip_fade.png.  So I need to set up each one for this particular experience in sequential order to fade in, fade out, and appear and disappear in timed intervals onClick of the interactive button in the screenshot - the one that looks like a universal "share" button.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code :-)

```
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 300;

    function showDiv() {
        $("div.fader").fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 7 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<% if Request("interactive") = "on" then %>
<form name="tutorial">

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation1" style="font-size:1em;" ></div><div id="tutorial1" class="tutorial createquestion1">Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation2" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial2" class="tutorial createquestion2">Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation3" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial3" class="tutorial createquestion3">Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation4">QUICK TIP</div><div class="arrow-n arrowlocation4" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial4" class="quicktip createquestion4">To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation5" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial5" class="tutorial createquestion5">Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-e arrowlocation6" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial6" class="tutorial createquestion6">Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation7" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation7">QUICK TIP</div>
<div id="tutorial7" class="quicktip createquestion7"> Click on this icon to open and close sections that you don't use. These will remain closed whenever you visit this page until you open them again.</div></div></form>


<% end if %>
```